# Vue computed issue - when will it compute again

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue computed has already perplexed me for a while

when will it compute again

condition1:

```
data() {
  return {
    cart:{
      item:{
        nums: 10,
        price: 10
      }
    }
  };
},
computed: {
  total() {
    return this.cart.item.nums * this.cart.item.price
  }
},
methods:{
  set(){
    this.cart.item = {
       nums: 5,
       price: 5
    }
  }
}
```

computed will work

---

condition2:

```
data() {
  return {
    cart: [{
        nums: 10,
        price: 10
    }]
  };
},
computed: {
  total() {
    return this.cart[0].nums * this.cart[0].price
  }
},
methods:{
  set(){
    this.cart[0] = {
       nums: 5,
       price: 5
    }
  }
}
```

computed won't work

---

I know this is the solution, but why?

```
methods:{
  set(){
    this.cart[0].nums = 5
    this.cart[0].price = 5
    }
  }
}
```

why didn't it be observed in condition2 ?

why Vue don't want it be observed ?

Comment: That is a unavoidable feature with JS: [if you mutate individual elements of the array, VueJS is unable to pick it up](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn’t-the-DOM-updating).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reactivity with objects and arrays is a bit finicky with Vue. With other variables it is easy to detect when they are changed, but with objects and arrays it is not always possible to detect whenever something in the object/array has been changed. (That is, without Proxies, which will come in Vue 3.x)

In your case, `total` will be recalculated if `this.cart` is marked as changed, `this.cart[0]` is marked as changed or if `this.cart[0].nums` or `this.cart[0].price` is changed. The problem is that you are replacing the object in `this.cart[0]`. This means that `this.cart[0].price` and `nums` do not change, because those still point to the old object. Apparently, `this.cart[0]` and `this.cart` are not marked as changed, so Vue still believes `total` to be up-to-date.

There are several ways to get around this. One is to use Vue's helper methods to work with objects/arrays, namely `Vue.set`, `Vue.delete`. You can access them in your SFC with `this.$set` or `this.$delete`. As `this.$set` explicitly marks whatever you pass as first argument as "changed", your total will also be updated.

```
this.$set(this.cart, 0, {
  nums: 2,
  price: 100
});
```

Another way is to modify the object itself, rather than replacing it. Since you are still working with the same object, Vue will detect that `this.cart[0]` has changed.

```
setItem() {
  this.cart[0] = Object.assign(
    this.cart[0],
    {
      nums: 5,
      price: 5
    }
  );
}
```

Another way is to use one of the many array methods. In your case, you could use Array.prototype.splice. As this is a function call, Vue can detect that the function is called and can mark the correct items as changed, which will trigger an update of anything that relies on it.

```
this.cart.splice(0, 1, {
  nums: 50,
  price: 10
});
```

[image: Edit Vue + Vuex + VueRouter template]

Comment: But I also replaced the object( this.cart.item ) in condition1.

why did Vue know `this.cart.item.nums` and `price`  was changed in this case?

Comment: It works there, because you are changing a key that already exists on the object. The only problem with objects I know of is when you try to set a key that did not previously exist. For example, if you tried to set the `title` key of the item in the cart, it would not update anything, because `title` was not in the object when you set it first. Normally you would need to call `this.$set` to get that to work.