# why vue change specific array member not update dom

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to know why I changed the specific item of an array and the page doesn't update. I know doc of vue.js points out that:

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`.

It says we should do that, but I don't know why. And I've found a similar question([Vue computed issue - when will it compute again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54841843/vue-computed-issue-when-will-it-compute-again/54842038#54842038)) about that.

Here is some code from the question above:

```
// works well

data() {
  return {
    cart: {
      item: {
        nums: 10,
        price: 10,
      },
    },
  }
},
computed: {
  total() {
    return this.cart.item.nums * this.cart.item.price
  },
},
methods: {
  set() {
    //why it worked.
    this.cart.item = {
      nums: 5,
      price: 5,
    }
  },
},

// oops! not working!

data() {
  return {
    cart: [
      {
        nums: 10,
        price: 10,
      },
    ],
  }
},
computed: {
  total() {
    return this.cart[0].nums * this.cart[0].price
  },
},
methods: {
  set() {
    this.cart[0] = {
      nums: 5,
      price: 5,
    }
  },
},
```

I'm confused about the answer from the question:

> total will be recalculated if `this.cart` is marked as changed, `this.cart[0]` is marked as changed or if `this.cart[0].nums` or `this.cart[0].price` is changed. The problem is that you are replacing the object in `this.cart[0]`. This means that `this.cart[0].price` and nums do not change, because those still point to the old object.

If I have replaced the object in `this.cart[0]`, why `this.cart[0]` isn't marked as changed? why `this.cart[0].price` and `nums` still point to old object? **I have changed the this.cart[0]! right?**

And why in the first situation it works well? **also replace the object** . What's the difference between the two scenarios?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vue is pretty explicit about this. It's a JavaScript limitation. JavaScript does not support the ability to detect when an array element changes, only when arrays change size as a result of adding or removing elements. Therefore replacing an element is not detectable.

What Vue does behind the scenes is sets up mechanics to watch for when objects change, which is something JavaScript *does* support. So array elements that are objects are things Vue can detect changes for. Since Vue cannot detect an array element being replaced, it doesn't know to stop looking at the old object and start looking at the new one.

The answer is also well-documented: if you want to update an item in an array, then use `Vue.set()`. This allows Vue to know that the array element is changing, so it knows to stop looking at the old object and start looking at the new one.

The solution therefore looks something like this:

```
Vue.set(this.cart, 0, {nums: 5, price: 5});
```

Comment: To summarise.Vue detect object changes. but not array members being replaced.if the code is this.cart[0].num = 5(as mentioned in the original question) , it will update the dom.  right?

Comment: @Archsx Correct. Vue should be capable of detecting that kind of change easily.

Answer (score 3):

### To make it short: Arrays are not registered reactive.

To assign a value use one of those equivalents:

- `Vue.set(array, index, value)`
- `vm.$set(array, index, value)`
- `array.splice(index, 1, value)`

  ---

### In the [`Observer`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/369dbe711a037b04612bca2f2e961282bdbb9153/src/core/observer/index.js#L37) class `constructor(value)` it is distinguished between Array and not Array:

```
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
  // steps through all indices
  this.observeArray(value)
} else {
  // steps through all keys
  this.walk(value)
}
```

*But what is `this.observeArray(value: Array)`* ?

## For Arrays it actually just calls `new Observer(value[index])` - the `constructor(value[index])`

#### There is *no* `getter` *nor* `setter` placed to watch for changes in this iteration over an Array

---

To inspect the second path: `this.walk(obj: Object)`:

It calls `defineReactive(obj, keys[i])` wich will in a simplified version will do:

```
defineReactive(obj, key=keys[i]){
  let val = obj[key]
  Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {

    get(){
      // registers in Deb
      dep.depend()
      // if array also 
      return val
    },
    set(newVal){

      val = newVal
      // adds to subscriber
      deb.notify()
    }
  })
}
```

---

#### But array proptotypes are patched to use the Observer [`this.__ob__.deb` to notify](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/369dbe711a037b04612bca2f2e961282bdbb9153/src/core/observer/array.js#L42) on usage.

---

### An alternative is the usage of [set](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/33e669b22f69a1f9c9147528360fe0bba85534f0/src/core/observer/index.js#L201) registered as:

- [`Vue.prototype.$set`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/33e669b22f69a1f9c9147528360fe0bba85534f0/src/core/instance/state.js#L342)
- [`Vue.set`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/369dbe711a037b04612bca2f2e961282bdbb9153/src/core/global-api/index.js#L44)

#### For Arrays `Vue.set(array, index, value)` calls `array.splice(index, 1, value)` and this again is the same as `ob.observeArray(value)` and `ob.deb.notify()`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for your `set()` method instead of use `Vue.set()` can be:

```
set() {
    this.cart.splice(0, 1, {
      nums: 5,
      price: 5,
    });
  },
```