# how add array of objects to data in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

please help with .$set data on vue , after read docs of vuejs.org I did not realize what must be index in $set when my data is already null and also syntax I need to write. please provide the syntax need for set data in this specific example. thank you.

```
//in vue js components:
data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: null
    };
computed: {
    onLoadColumns() {
      // some logic here (manipulate received props from parent)
      // logic bring this [{},{},{}]
      // sth = [{},{},{}]

      // now want to .$set() , (or maybe $add()) that array to data obj for reactivity.

      // what syntax look like? this below didn't work.
      this.$set(this.columnsDef, 0, sth);
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. Are you talking about setters and getters ?

Comment: i want add array of objects to my data. i have no idea how do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615156/why-vue-change-specific-array-member-not-update-dom/57616094#57616094 - [] instead null

Answer (score 0):

You have a **typo**: should be `this.$set(this.columnDef, 0, sth);`. Not `this.columnsDef` - without **s**.

Also try to init you `columnDef` with `[]` in `data`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    columnDefs: []
  }
},
```

Or set empty array right before assigning to zero index:

```js
this.columnDef = []
this.$set(this.columnDef, 0, sth)
```

Comment: thanks that worked with empty array but docs say must not do that (ag-grid) any way thanks.